# Solve for $θ$: $θ − sin(θ) = \frac{2A}{r^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone assist here?
$$
\theta − \sin{\theta} = \frac{2A}{r^2} 
$$
How would I solve for $\theta$?

My precalc is quite rusty.  Basically looking for way to get either the angle of a segment or the height of one using radius and area.

Comment: I don't think that there is an algebraic solution to this. But if you know $A$ and $r$, you can numerically find the answer.

Comment: *Welcome to the site !* Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3501222/angle-subtended-at-the-centre-by-a-segment-of-a-circle/3508711#3508711

Comment: Thank you, Claude!!  That got me where I wanted! :D

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Hmmm. Ingenious. I had to upvote your earlier answer!

Comment: Yes it did thank you Claude!